# A faster way to find the quadratic extensions of a field extension?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions, galois-connections

The usual method I have for finding Galois correspondence goes like this :

Say we have the Splitting field of $x^4-3$, i.e. $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{3})$.

Then it's generating automorphisms are those that permute the elements of the roots of the minimal polynomial while keeping the other fixed, in this case they are $\sigma:i\rightarrow i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow i\sqrt[4]{3} $ and 
$\tau :i\rightarrow - i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow \sqrt[4]{3} $ they generate the eight automorphisms of the Galois group:

$\phi_1:i\rightarrow i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow \sqrt[4]{3} $

$\phi_2:i\rightarrow i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow i\sqrt[4]{3} $

$\phi_3:i\rightarrow  i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow -\sqrt[4]{3} $

$\phi_4:i\rightarrow  i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow -i\sqrt[4]{3} $

$\phi_5:i\rightarrow - i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow \sqrt[4]{3} $

$\phi_6:i\rightarrow - i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow i\sqrt[4]{3} $

$\phi_7:i\rightarrow - i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow -\sqrt[4]{3} $

$\phi_8:i\rightarrow - i, \sqrt[4]{3}\rightarrow -i\sqrt[4]{3} $

Now say we wanted to find all quadratic extensions , then the way I know how to it is to look at these automorphism , see which are order 4 ( as they'll correspond to a fixed field of degree 2 ) and test the elements of $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{3})$ with each automorphism one by one and see what remains fixed... But this is a horribly long and tedious way Can anyone show me how to it more efficiently ?

I also know that we can look at the Galois group directly see which subgroups are order 4 and test the automorphisms that way but it amounts to the same thing. I feel their may be some method that will involve the minimal polynomials and how the split in different fields but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: You may not get all the quadratic extensions as fixed fields of automorphism of order four. The Galois group may well have non-cyclic subgroups of order four (necessarily isomorphic to the Klein Viergruppe). And the fixed field of such a subgroup (generated by two commuting automorphisms of order two) is also a quadratic extension.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what method could we then use to obtain all quadratic extensions ?

Comment: Anyway, you get more efficient at this by working out several examples. Also, often you can identify such subfields by staring at the numbers in your field. You know that a quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ looks like $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$ for some $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. Furthermore, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt m)$ are distinct unless $m/n$ is the square of a rational. Can you see that $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt{-1}$ are in your field? How many more do you need to find?

Comment: Using Galois theory means that you need to give full censuses of subgroups of the Galois group. Here the Galois group is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$. Can you list all its subgroups right away? How many of order four?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 3 of order 4 , ah I see now the method I used above will not work … So the best method is to look directly at the group and then examine the effect on the splitting field elements.

Comment: What I was getting at is that you should also try and spot obvious subfields and find the corresponding subgroups. A few of those will be easy, and when you have the list of all subgroups, and you can then start tinkering with the subgroups not yet "used".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already found that the Galois group is generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$, which have orders $4$ and $2$, respectively, and it is not hard to see that $\sigma\tau=\tau\sigma^{-1}$. This means the Galois group is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $8$.

The quadratic subfields of the splitting field correspond precisely to the subgroups of index $2$ in the Galois group, i.e. the subgroups of order $4$. By basic group theory there are precisely three such subgroups.

As noted in the comments, it is easy to spot a few quadratic subfields of $\Bbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{3})$. The field contains the elements $i$, $(\sqrt[4]{3})^2$ and $i(\sqrt[4]{3})^2$, and hence it contains the quadratic subfields $\Bbb{Q}(i)$, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. It is a simple exercise to show that these are distinct, and by the argument above these must be  *all* quadratic subfields.

It is then perhaps a nice exercise to formally verify that you indeed obtain these fields as the fixed fields of the three subgroups of index $2$ in the Galois group. But I hope this shows that this method is in general *not* the easiest way to find the desired subfields; it is often easier to look at the known elements of the subfield.

Answer (score 0):

Given a galois extension *N/K* with group *G*, it would of course be desirable to have the maximal amount of information on *G* in order to determine the subextensions of *N/K*. But shortcuts are possible in case the structure of *G* is amenable enough. For example, if *G* is a *p*-group, i.e. a group of order equal to a power of a prime *p*, let *L/K* be the compositum of all the subextensions which are cyclic of degree *p* over *K*. Obviously $Gal(L/K)\cong G/[G,G]G^p$, where $[G,G]G^p$ is the so called Frattini subgroup, generated by the commutators and the $p$-th powers. If we consider $G/[G,G]G^p$ as a vector space of dimension $d$ over $\mathbf F_p$, the number of subgroups of order $p$ contained in it is straightforwardly equal to $(p^d-1)/(p-1)$. Note also that the center of a $p$-group is always non trivial.

In your case here, $p=2$ and $G$ is the dihedral group $D_8$, whose center has necessarily order 2 (why ?), so that the Frattini quotient has order 4. It follows that the number of quadratic subextensions is 3 . These are naturally $\mathbf Q(i), \mathbf Q(\sqrt3)$ and $\mathbf Q(i\sqrt 3)$.